# Get data on PayPal subscription profile without access to original IPN

Tags: paypal

One of my customers had a website hosted on FusionHQ with subscription profiles through PayPal. When migrating the payments, I guessed I could just change the IPN and would get the new messages. But it seems that Fusion has manually set *nofify_url* parameters for their subscription profiles and there seems to be no way to change the *notify_url*.

Though slightly annoying, I guessed I could still use the classic payments API to get information and do something stupid like checking the subscribers' status on the assumed expiration date. But, it turned out that PayPal doesn't allow it because the specific API FusionHQ has used, with the following error message:

> Subscription Profiles not supported by Recurring Payment APIs.

The thing is that there is no way I can get access to the old IPN server since it is on FusionHQ's domain. After searching through StackOverflow, I've really lost all hope of doing this in a decent way, and I'm about to redirect my customer's PayPal emails to some SMTP bot to parse them and give me the transactions update. But this is obviously a very crappy and unreliable way. So, does anyone have any idea of what to do?